# PHP GetElementsByTagName Error

Tags: php

I wrote a very long code and I had to retrieve alot of tags from a website, for example the title, h1, h2, h3, a, p and so on.I firstly did this with preg_match but realised very soon this is the wrong way of doing it. So i started using this:

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname){
    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadHTML($string);
    $return = array();
    foreach($d->getElementsByTagName($tagname) as $item){
        $return[] = $item->textContent;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

and to retrieve a tag: `$title = getTextBetweenTags($contents, 'title');`

This worked fine on the testpage is was using, which was a wikipedia page.

But as soon as i tested it on another page it gave me alot of errors like these:

`Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! in Entity`

and after this one alot of:

`Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,`

I did some research and found out that it's expecting a `'&amp;'` instead of `&` for example so after every 'special character' it expects a `;` but as it uses `file_get_contents` to retrieve the contents (`$file_contents = file_get_contents($url);`). I REALLY don't want to go back to `preg_match` (for obvious reasons) So i'm asking if maybe of you knows how to fix my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the world of parsing invalid html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this problem using [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors). Currently, your function calls `loadHTML()` every time the function is called. I would just load the HTML outside the function and pass it as a parameter.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$errorState = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); // don't display errors
$dom->loadHTML($string);
libxml_use_internal_errors($errorState); // reset the state

function getTextBetweenTags(DOMDocument $dom, $string, $tagname) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName($tagname) as $item){
        $return[] = $item->textContent;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$string = file_get_contents($url);
$title = getTextBetweenTags($dom, $string, 'title');
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, it works alot more than it used to! However it won't let me find the `title` and the `i` anymore. Also it somehow messed up my if statements. I don't know if you have time to take a look at this? I will edit my question if you're interested you can take a look.

Comment: Alright i fixed my problem, i included the wrong `$` inside the the `$dom->loadHTML($string);`. Thanks for your help. Accepted your answer.